# Kernel panic during sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, crash, kernel-panic

4 days ago my 2017 MacBook Pro started exhibiting a strange behaviour. Basically when it's in sleep mode, it crashes and when I open it I have to boot it again and the report shows a kernel panic, that is almost always identical, that says something like

```
Fatal error occurred. CSTS=0xffffffff
. FW Revision=CXS4JA0Q\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IONVMeFamily/IONVMeFamily-356.30.6/IONVMeController.cpp:5275
```

I haven't installed anything new in these days, I resetted the NVRAM, the RMC, I did diagnostic and first aid on the SSD, the problem is still there. Maybe it is also worth noting that the very first time that it happened there was also a flashing box with a question mark, but this happened only the first time.

Right now I have installed an app, Insomnia X, that prevents the laptop to go in sleep mode when I close the lid, but I would like to solve this problem.

I'm hesitant to visit the Apple Store to check the hardware as I cannot go until the end of the month.

Is there a way to know if this is software or hardware in the mean time?

Comment: I literally have the exact same problem and haven't been able to solve it. My brand new Macbook pro started doing it just within the past few weeks. im getting the same fatal error code and everything.

Answer (score 2):

Try booting the MacBook Pro into Recovery or Internet Recovery mode (hold down cmd-R when booting for Recovery mode, or option-cmd-R for Internet Recovery mode).

Now you have booted in a "known good" configuration of software which is unaffected by any changed you may have made to the normal operating system on the Mac.

If sleep mode works fine here without kernel panics - you'll know that you have a software related problem.

Comment: I tried with safe boot and I still got a kernel panic (the strange thing is that it doesn't happen everytime it goes to sleep mode, just 2-3 times per day). I will try with this recovery mode!

Comment: This is the best solution - back up your data and erase the hard drive and install clean OS. If that fails as well, you can be quite confident a hardware repair / delay / trip to Apple is the next step. If not, you can know it's software and restore all your data and then triage what specific item or setting or app if the issue recurs after you do the erase and restore of data.